# Calculate row value based on previous and actual row values

Tags: mysql

Hi everyone and thanks for your help.
I have the following situation: a table called statements that contains fields **id**(int), **stmnt_date**(date), **debit**(double), **credit**(double) and **balance**(double)
[image: Structure of my table]

I want to calculate the balance following these rules:

The first row balance (**chronologically**) = debit - credit and for the rest of the rows

**current row balance = chronologically previous row balance + current row debit - current row credit**

As you can see on the picture above the rows are not arranged by date and that's why I used the word chronologically twice to emphasize on the importance of the stmnt_date value.

Thank you very much for your help.